# Avoid merge conflic when commit depend on another commit on code review

Tags: git, gerrit

I have the following tree in Git:

```
      A new_branch
     /
B---C---D---E master
```

`A` is using the changes from `C`. `C` is on remote master on Gerrit waiting for code review.

Which would now be the ideal way to push `A` to remote master on 
Gerrit without introducing any merge conflicts?

Comment: Why would there be any conflict here?  Git will happily merge C when either C's code review is approved or when A's code review is approved.

Comment: "push `A` to gerrit" is not clear, you mean push to the remote `master`?

Comment: @john zwinck Ok all good then

Answer (score 0):

The IDEAL way is not to base commit A in commit C because it still waiting for code review. You must only base your work in merged (submitted) commits. So, in your example, you should work in parallel with C like this:

```
  A new_branch
 /
B---C---D---E master
```

Actually, if you are saying that commit C is still waiting for code review so this is the correct way to draw the schema:

```
  A new_branch
 /
B master
 \
  C---D---E waiting for review
```

If you really need to work based on commit C then you'll push to Gerrit the same way as ever:

```
$ git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

But you need to have in mind that if during the review process the commit C was changed then you'll need to rebase the commit A for the new commit C' before it can be merged to master.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are used to work with reviewers.

It's not uncommon to have multiple commits to review in the relation chain.
The only thing that you need to keep in mind is to **properly highlight the relation chain** there. For example, in the commit message `[<commit-ID>] (<child-ID>) <message>`.

IMHO, this is the best way to handle scenarios such as :

- commit B : normal feature
- commit C : handy plug-in library
- commit A : feature relying on handy plug-in
- commit D : other feature relying on handy plug-in